# Weak Holomorphicity: Notation clarification.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

A function $f\in L^2(D)$ is *weakly holomorphic* if, for every $\phi\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(D)$, $$\int_D f\partial_{\bar{z}}\phi = 0.$$ I'm trying to show that each such $f$ is smooth on the interior of $D$ and is in fact a strong solution to $\partial_{\bar{z}}f=0$; i.e., $f$ is holomorphic in the usual sense. But, shouldn't $\partial_{\bar{z}} \phi$ be zero everywhere?

Update: No, it shouldn't. It's smooth in that its partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ exist and are continuous. It's not holomorphic since, in particular, a bounded holomorphic function is constant (in this case, 0).

Comment: $\partial_{\bar z}\phi$ need not be $0$. The assumption is that $\phi$ has *real* derivatives of any order, not necessarily that $\phi$ is holomorphic. In fact, since $\phi$ has compact support, $\phi$ can't be holomorphic unless it vanishes identically.

Comment: Ah, that's right. That settles it. Thanks.

Comment: @mrf That's an answer, not a comment...

Comment: @5pm You're right, even though it was on the short side.

Comment: I do not see why mrf's comment answers the question whether every weakly holomorphic $f$ is holomorphic. Ellipticity of the Cauchy-Riemann operator is the key word.

Comment: @Jochen That's not what is asked here.

Comment: Got it. Reverting the edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial_{\bar z}\phi$ need not be 0. The assumption is that $\phi$ has *real* derivatives of any order (i.e. $\partial_x \phi$ and $\partial_y\phi$), not necessarily that $\phi$ is holomorphic. In fact, since $\phi$ has compact support, $\phi$ can't be holomorphic unless it vanishes identically.